# Qt: How to catch QDateEdit click event?

Tags: c++, qt, click, qwidget, qevent

I'm trying to catch mouse click on `QDateEdit` widget by handling `QEvent::MouseButtonRelease` event, but can't find a way to do it. I tried to override `QWidget::event` method of the parent widget, but it seems that events go through children to parent, and `QDateEdit` internally handles those events without propagating to a parent. Is there any correct solution or workaround?

Comment: Why do you need to catch mouse click? There is a bunch of methods to detect changes in a QDateTimeEdit and, maybe, handling mouse events are not the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QDateEdit` extends a `QWidget` class. So you can just inherit `QDateEdit` and override `virtual void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)` function and do what you want there.

**Update:**

Function `mouseReleaseEvent` is really not invoke.

Try to install an event filter to the line edit in `QDateEdit`. Example:

MyDateEdit.h

```
#include <QDateEdit>

class MyDateEdit : public QDateEdit
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  MyDateEdit(QWidget *parent = 0);
  bool eventFilter(QObject* object, QEvent* event) override;
};
```

MyDateEdit.cpp

```
#include "MyDateEdit.h"    
#include <QDebug>
#include <QEvent>
#include <QLineEdit>

MyDateEdit::MyDateEdit(QWidget *parent) : QDateEdit (parent)
{
  installEventFilter(this);
  lineEdit()->installEventFilter(this);
}

bool MyDateEdit::eventFilter(QObject* object, QEvent* event)
{
  if (object == this || object == lineEdit())
  {
    if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease)
    {
      qDebug() << "Mouse release event";
    }
  }    
  return QDateEdit::eventFilter(object, event);
}
```

Comment: I tried to do that, but QDateEdit never receive mouseReleaseEvent. It is probably because the underlying QLineEdit widget doesn't propagate it to the parent

Comment: Thanks, lineEdit() method is just what I need. I haven't noticed this useful method in QAbstractSpinBox

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to install an eventFilter. The [eventFilter section](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter) of the Qt documentation provides an example of how it is use.

Your window class should override `eventFilter`

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
  if (obj == dateEdit) {
    if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress) {
        // do what you want to do
        // alternatively use QEvent::MouseButtonRelease 
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
  } else {
    // pass the event on to the parent class
    return QMainWindow::eventFilter(obj, event);
  }
}
```

In your window constructor, install the filter on the actual widget:

```
dateEdit->installEventFilter(this);
```

Comment: I tried it, but QEvent::MouseButtonPress event coming to eventFilter only when I press to a drop-down arrow of a QDateEdit widget

Comment: True enough. I guess it makes sense to have the widget swallow those since you presumably want it to handle the user interaction in order to get a date. So, the question is what exactly are you wanting to do upon mouse button release?

Comment: The goal was a logging all user interactions, including clicks on date widgets, even when those widgets already have a focus, i.e. focus events is not that I just need